# ios UITextChecker unable to add word into dictionary

Tags: ios, dictionary

I am trying to add a word into the iOS dictionary via `UITextChecker`
using this:

```
[UITextChecker learnWord:@"whatishouldadd"];

[UITextChecker hasLearnedWord::@"whatishouldadd"]<--return true
```

However, when I fire up notes and type the above, it is underlined with red.

**Another example:** 
I try to add `happizer` inside the dictionary using the above. However, when I fire notes, `happier` is prompted.

May I know if the function `learnWord` actually adds work into the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

According to the `UITextChecker` class reference, [learnWord](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextChecker_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UITextChecker/learnWord%3a)...

> "Tells the text checker to learn the specified word so that it is not evaluated as misspelled."

Since you're creating the `UITextChecker` inside of your App, it's your `UITextChecker` that is learning the word- not the `iPhone` dictionary as a whole. Therefore, words taught inside of the App will not be available globally.

Comment: I see... There is really no way to learn the word afterall right?

Comment: Well, no way using a Public API. There is a file (supposedly located at /private/var/mobile/Library/Keyboard/dynamic-text.dat, but I haven't confirmed this) that stores the words that iOS has added, and if that file was modified then the words would be added globally. Apple would certainly reject an app that does this, however, so you shouldn't do so unless the app is for personal use (or jailbreak).